# How to make same-height HTML page elements with jQuery

Tags: jquery, dynamic

The task is to make elements on a page of the same height. There's a simple well-known jQuery code snippet that does that (get all heights using `.height()`, find the maximal one and assign via `.css('height':maxHeight)`-like call).

However, if the elements themselves contain dynamic content (i.e. HTML snippet filled with 'I like' Facebook snippet), the above doesn't work. I see the elements made of equal heights, then the dynamic content is loaded and heights become different once again.

Binding height-reassigning function to `.resize` event of any/all elements doesn't help.

Is there a simple way to know when all the dynamic content has loaded, to call the height reassignment as the last action?

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

(in head)

```
$(window).load(function () {...your resizing code...});
```

Window load is better than document ready for Chrome due to how it loads images.

Comment: That isn't correct. `$(document).ready()` is fired before images are loaded. It's fired when the DOM is ready, which should be very early on.

Comment: What isn't correct?  I told him to use load and not ready for that reason.

Comment: That won't account for AJAX-loaded content either. You'll need to figure out a way to find out when those content boxes load.

Comment: Of course it won't.  AJAX loaded content might be loaded two days later.  It goes without saying that he would need his code to run again.

Comment: Alas, this doesn't always work. Looks like I need to re-apply height correction on an 'content changed' event, but looks like there is no such event.